# Setup Tomcat libraries dependencies in maven POM

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

I am currently migrating our build process from Eclipse/Ant to Maven/M2Eclipse/Artifactory.
I have a Webapp as a WTP project in Eclipse.
I have migrated it to Maven with m2eclipse.

The compilation runs fine from the Eclipse IDE.

However, when I try to compile from Maven CLI (`mvn clean & mvn compile`), Maven complains about not finding the libraries provided by the Tomcat Environment (like *annotations-api*, *servlet-api*, etc, ...).

Fair enough : Indeed, these dependencies are provided by WTP, as `Java resources / Libraries / ApacheTomcat6`. Maven is not aware of them.

I could deactivate this in the build path, and add each corresponding dependency in my POM, but I'm afraid this would lead Maven to deploy them again in my webapp (`WEB-INF/libs`).

So, what is the good way to say to maven "this application will run in a well known environment, providing the following libraries  ". Is there some common Tomcat POM that I could add as a dependency ?

Thanks in advance for your advice.
regards,

Raphael

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to handle this is to declare these dependencies with scope `provided`.  These dependencies will be available for compile and test, but will not be packaged by maven into the webapp. For example,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Above is the way you need to define in your pom. change the scope to provided so maven does not include those jars in your final build.

Comment: Thanks,Do you know if Tomcat provides a POM project with all libraries already listed as "provided" ? I could then add it as a dependency.

Comment: @RaphaelJolivet that would be neat, also looking for this (but for Glassfish, actually). Did you find anything?

Comment: Is it possible to have m2eclipse (or mvn eclipse:eclispe) add the dependencies to the generated project/classpath ?